# An Error Was Encountered simple mail sending localhost to server not working

Tags: php, smtp, syntax-error

My Code :

```
<?php

class Email extends CI_Controller
{

function index()
{

        $this->load->library('email');

        $config = Array(

            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp:gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => 'v@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'facebook@123',
            'charset'   =>  'utf-8',
            'newline'=>"\r\n"
        );



        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('vaghasiamit@gmail.com','Elsner');

        $this->email->to('vaghasiamit@gmail.com');

        $this->email->subject('This is Test email');

        $this->email->message('hi');


        $this->email->send();








        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "email sent";


        }
        else
        {

            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }


}
```

}

and Error  is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No
>   such host is known.
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2023
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2\application\controllers\email.php Line: 37
>   Function: send
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp:gmail.com:465
>   (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
>   )
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2023
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2\application\controllers\email.php Line: 37
>   Function: send
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Answer (score -1):

Use `smtp.gmail.com` instead of `smtp:gmail.com` as hostname.

```
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'
```

Comment: Is it exactly the same error? `Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp:gmail.com:465`